# Creating an array of objects help needed

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

I am trying to make an array of objects. I have Two classes, the main and another class for the methods. The one i am running the program in is TestTrivia, the class with all the methods for TestTrivia is Question. Constructor for this class is 
          public Question()
        {
          question = "null";
         answer = "null";
         pointValue = 0;
    }
i am trying to do something like this 
       Person personArray[] = new Person[5];

```
   for(int i=0; i< personArray.length; i++)
   {
    personArray[i] = new Person();
  }
```

So i have tried 
        Question QuestionArray[] = new Question[5];
      for(int i=0; i< QuestionArray.length; i++)
       {
        QuestionArray[i] = new Question();
      }
I have tried to use it in both classes, the main and the one full of methods. It should go into the main class correct? The error i am getting is the whole for statement is underlined and says: illegal start type cannot find symbol symbol: class i location: class triviagame.TriviaGame package QuestionArray does not exist
triviagame is the package name, "TriviaGame" is the class name, "Question" is another class name.

Comment: Please start variable names with lower case, and arrays are typically declared as `Question[] questionArray` in Java (although I'd call it `questions`). Please show the exact code you're trying, not just a fragment.

Comment: the rest of the code is not really needed for this question, i am just trying to figure out why it is not working, no other method or line of code will affect this, that much i do know. I do not want to confuse people with this giant bulk of code when none of it directly or indirectly affects trying to make an array of objects

Comment: Oh, well, good luck then. You don't think it's a little weird it's referring to `class i`? There's absolutely nothing wrong with the fragment in isolation except for the misleading variable name.

Comment: I am just going off my book, and in all the examples it uses i or index.

Comment: As I said, nothing is wrong with the code as shown. That's why I believe the issue has to do with something besides the code as shown, and why I asked for its context. The misleading variable name is `QuestionArray`, not `i`.

Comment: Is there a way i can send you a personal message or send you the code i am working on? or should i just edit the main question

Comment: Additional information should be edited into the original question.

Comment: I just Put my full class in there, my Question class and my TriviaGame Class

Comment: See answer. The rest of the code was needed for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop code needs to be within a method, like `main`.

Also, if they are not in the same package, you will need to import classes not in the "current" package. For example, if `Question` is in the default package, it will need to be imported into the `TriviaGame` class.

```
package triviagame;

import Question;

public class TriviaGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the New Age Trivia game");
        System.out.println("You will be asked five questions, let us begin");
        Question questionArray[] = new Question[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < questionArray.length; i++) {
            questionArray[i] = new Question();
        }
    }
}
```

If the `Question` class is in the `triviagame` package as well, the import is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah i just noticed, i copied from another place and i copied it outside of the main block, still making those simple mistakes

Comment: @RedDragon The simple mistakes never stop ;) They just get easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to make methods calls outside of a method or constructor or initializer block. Don't do this, but instead make sure your code is in the proper location such as in the main or another method.

```
public class TriviaGame {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      System.out.println("Welcome to the New Age Trivia game");
      System.out.println("You will be asked five questions, let us begin");
   }

   // this code is sitting out in the middle of no-where
   Question questionArray[] = new Question[5];
   for(int i=0; i< questionArray.length; i++)
   {
     questionArray[i] = new Question();
   }

}
```

Comment: Seems i am not done with making simple mistakes yet, i copied it outside the block

Comment: @RedDragon: then you'll want to copy it *inside* the block.